# How can i get the values from Listview stored in database to another activity? Using Android and Mysql

Tags: android, mysql, listview, android-activity

Here i am using Android with mysql database. I have created the tables, and it's also storing the values to database. And It also showing at Listview, But when i am trying to Click on the Item in Listview. It's not going to another activity. Please help me out.

Here is my code in adapter

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_entries, null, true);

        TextView tvTitleEntry = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvTitleEntry);
        TextView tvCityEntry = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvCityEntry);

        final Entry entry = entryList.get(position);

        tvTitleEntry.setText(entry.getTitle());
        tvCityEntry.setText(entry.getCity());

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String title = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewEntry.class);
                i.putExtra("title", title);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        return listViewItem;
    }
}
```

Another activity (ViewEntry class) code

```
    TextView tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String title = i.getStringExtra("title");
    tvTitle.setText(title);
```

logcat

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
                                                                                               at com.example.arko.torranboapplicationentry.EntriesActivity$EntryAdapter$1.onItemClick(EntriesActivity.java:125)
                                                                                               at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
                                                                                               at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
                                                                                               at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3057)
                                                                                               at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3864)
                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: try setting OnItemClickListener in your activity..not adapter and `((TextView) view).getText().toString();` --> here view is your listview item view

Comment: Nop it's not working, still getting the same error

Comment: get the context from the activity when you are setting adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> String title = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

In this line, You are trying to cast the listview item's view as textview which rises the exception.

Change it as onclicklistener, And also get the textview from your listview item's view

```
 listViewItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
                String title = ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitleEntry)).getText().toString();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewEntry.class);
                i.putExtra("title", title);
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            String title = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
            Intent i = new Intent(activity , ViewEntry.class);
            i.putExtra("title", title);
            startActivity(i);

    }
});
```

And add `private Activity activity ; this.activity = activity ;` into  constructor

Answer (score 0):

normally **setOnItemClickListener** is not in getView()

I made some basic structure. Hope it's helpful.

plus : you should use holder pattern after getting used to with it.

**TestActivity.class**

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

private Context mContext;
private Activity mActivity;

private ListView listView;
private MyAdapter myAdapter;
private ArrayList<MyAdapter.MyData> data;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_activity);

    mContext = mActivity = this;

    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(mContext, data);
    listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String title =data.get(position).getTitle();
            Intent i = new Intent(mActivity , ViewEntry.class);
            i.putExtra("title", title);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
}


private void someProceeToLoadData(){
    MyAdapter.MyData testData1 = new MyAdapter.MyData(1, "James", "downtown");
    MyAdapter.MyData testData2 = new MyAdapter.MyData(1, "Smith" "New Town");
    data.add(testData1);
    data.add(testData2);

    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
}
```

**MyAdapter.clss**

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<MyData> items;

private LayoutInflater inflater;

public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MyData> items) {
    this.mContext = context;
    this.items = items;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public MyData getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return items.get(position).getId();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_entries, null, true);

    TextView tvTitleEntry = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvTitleEntry);
    TextView tvCityEntry = listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvCityEntry);

    final Entry entry = entryList.get(position);

    tvTitleEntry.setText(entry.getTitle());
    tvCityEntry.setText(entry.getCity());

    return listViewItem;
}

public static class MyData {
    long id;
    String title;
    String city;

    public MyData(long id, String name, String city) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = name;
        this.city = city;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
}
}
```